Is "Murphy's Law" researchable?
This universe is, IMHO, the worst of all places: Entropy makes it even worse all the time, quantum mechanics makes it unpredictable, and stupid and jerky humans makes it a living hell. Of course, the first two might be necessary for a logically consistent universe and the last isn't a logical necessity, maybe a little apocalypse can be very teaching to the survivors.
But Murphy's Law suggest there is even an additional malicious force involved. One is tempted to ask: Is Murphy's Law only a quip? Caused by our own observational bias? (If the traffic light was green for you and you got your train in time, you don't remember.)
Research, of course, would necessitate to find a "baseline": Given the world is at it is, how much bad stuff is statistically bound to happen? Actual experiments are possible!
My question is if this baseline is computable at all. "In principle but all bits of the universe wouldn't suffice even for an approximation" I consider as a legit answer, thus feel free to argue why not at all (quantum again?).

"The worst" is a big word, if you exert your imagination for a minute you can surely imagine far worse. And the fact that you are still alive and was able to post here is evidence that Murphy's law, taken literally and unconditionally, is false. As for researching, "bad stuff" is notoriously vague and ambiguous (your loss - my gain, as they say), as is "can" in "can go wrong". After all, we only observe one world, so it is hard to judge what can go and what cannot. Leibniz even dubbed this world "the best possible world", and he had as much 'evidence' as Murphy.

Murphy's Law is an adage or epigram, not a scientific or natural law. If taken literally, it's somewhere between clearly false (if we're talking about conceivable/philosophical possibilities) and entirely unprovable and unjustifiable (if one wants to assert that any worse things that can be conceived of are not possibilities).

I'm voting to close because this question isn't serious; it is intended to be amusing. "worst of all places", not knowing if Murphy's Law is a quip or not, experiments on whether toast lands butter-side down, and the last paragraph is incoherent. This might be an amusing quirky blog post, but it doesn't belong on this site.

@DavidGudeman: I'm dead serious, and reading the justified objection of Conifold even more: I say it would be highly interesting to find out how "evil" a "possible" universe is "by average". (Maybe by simulation?) I also doubt it's doable, but an answer would be profound regarding the theodicy problem.
